# Pivot to wide form based on contents of cells

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have got a large data table where certain parameters were measured either on

1. no particular side (I've called these "NoSide") or
2. both the right and the left sides.

```
myinput <- data.frame(Parameter=letters[1:10], NoSide=c(NA,NA,NA,1,3,3,2,0,1,NA), Right=c(2,3,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1), Left=c(0,1,4,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2))

> myinput
   Parameter NoSide Right Left
1          a     NA     2    0
2          b     NA     3    1
3          c     NA     1    4
4          d      1    NA   NA
5          e      3    NA   NA
6          f      3    NA   NA
7          g      2    NA   NA
8          h      0    NA   NA
9          i      1    NA   NA
10         j     NA     1    2
```

I would like the data to be displayed as follows in the wide form, as in this particular case, the measurements on the right and the left are discrete values that shouldn't be lumped together:

```
myheaders = c("a_Right","a_Left","b_Right","b_Left","c_Right","c_Left","d","e","f","g","h","i","j_Right","j_Left")
mydata = c(2,0,3,1,1,4,1,3,3,2,0,1,1,2)
myoutput = as.data.frame(t(mydata))
colnames(myoutput) <- myheaders
myoutput

> myoutput
  a_Right a_Left b_Right b_Left c_Right c_Left d e f g h i j_Right j_Left
1       2      0       3      1       1      4 1 3 3 2 0 1       1      2
```

Essentially, the contents of the NoSide, Right and Left columns are read from left to right and listed in the wide form, while omitting "NA" values. New column names should be created based on whether the values are derived from the "NoSide", "Right" or "Left" columns (ideally without "NoSide" in the name).

Have you got any suggestions on the easiest way to convert `myinput` to `myoutput`? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pivot_wider(myinput, 
 names_from = Parameter, values_from = NoSide:Left, names_vary='slowest',
 names_glue = "{Parameter}{if_else(.value=='NoSide','',str_c('_',.value))}") %>% 
select(!where(is.na))

# A tibble: 1 × 14
  a_Right a_Left b_Right b_Left c_Right c_Left     d     e     f     g     h     i j_Right j_Left
    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1       2      0       3      1       1      4     1     3     3     2     0     1       1      2
```

Comment: Your one liner is definitely more elegant than my approach. (: Wasn't aware of `names_vary`.  Have to check that out.

Answer (score 3):

While I don't understand why you want to reshape your data this way, you could achieve your desired result by first reshaping to wide, then getting rid of the `NA` columns and finally some reordering and renaming:

```r
myinput <- data.frame(
  Parameter = letters[1:10],
  NoSide = c(NA, NA, NA, 1, 3, 3, 2, 0, 1, NA),
  Right = c(2, 3, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1),
  Left = c(0, 1, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2)
)

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

myinput %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(
    names_from = Parameter,
    values_from = -Parameter,
    names_glue = "{Parameter}_{.value}"
  ) %>%
  dplyr::select(!where(~ all(is.na(.x)))) %>%
  dplyr::select(sort(names(.))) |>
  dplyr::rename_with(
    ~ gsub("_NoSide", "", .x),
    ends_with("NoSide")
  )
#> # A tibble: 1 × 14
#>   a_Left a_Right b_Left b_Right c_Left c_Right     d     e     f     g     h
#>    <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1      0       2      1       3      4       1     1     3     3     2     0
#> # ℹ 3 more variables: i <dbl>, j_Left <dbl>, j_Right <dbl>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

myinput %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(NoSide, Right, Left), names_to = "Side", values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(Parameter = if_else(Side == "NoSide", as.character(Parameter), paste(Parameter, Side, sep = "_"))) %>%
  select(-Side) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Parameter, values_from = value)

 a_Right a_Left b_Right b_Left c_Right c_Left     d     e     f     g     h     i j_Right j_Left
    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1       2      0       3      1       1      4     1     3     3     2     0     1       1      2
```